# Enhancing a search query written with regex to support whitespace

Tags: ruby

I have the following regex:

```
/("[^"]+"|[^\s]+:[^\s]+)/
```

If I gave it the following:

```
tag:closed  tag:open tag:Trello status:new
```

it will match these groups:

1. `tag:closed`
2. `tag:open`
3. `tag:Trello`
4. `status:new`

I tried to enhance it to support whitespace so that it matches:

```
tag:"don't merge"
```

I tried:

```
/("[^"]+"|[^\s]+:[^\s]+|["\w\s"]+)/
```

but that didn't work. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

http://rubular.com/r/DNWKz44BbF

You need to negate the doublequotes in your other match otherwise it's a shorter match for regex to use.

`([^\s]+:"[^"]+"|[^\s]+:[^\s"]+)`

Answer (score -3):

```
/(\S+:(?:"[^"]+"|\S+))/
```

.............................

Comment: Downvoted for lack of explanatory text. Seriously, if you can be troubled to type "........" you can take the time to explain your answer.